# Linking my static C++ library with libavutil cause to undefined reference

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, name-mangling

I'm facing some strange problem. I have a static library that uses the Ffmpeg libraries internally. For some reason I get the error:
`` undefined reference to `av_log_set_level(int) ``

the code is as follows:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
int some_func()
{
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET);        
}
```

As you can see the Ffmpeg libraries are enclosed into `extern "C"`.
I use CMake file, that looks like follows:

```make
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.23)

add_library(MyLib STATIC lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyLib  -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil)

add_executable(MyApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyApp  MyLib -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil)
```

But nothing helps, I still get the same error.

I've tried to check the symbols of my library with nm:

```
nm .MyLib.a | grep av_log_set_level
U _Z16av_log_set_leveli
```

the same function in libavutil:

```
nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.a | grep av_log_set_level
0000000000000ff0 T av_log_set_level
```

I guess that for some reason my static library uses c++ mangling and so it looks for the incorrect function, `_Z16av_log_set_leveli` instead of `av_log_set_level` that causes for undefined reference error. What can I do, how can I fix that?

The environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- g++ 9.4.0
- libavutil-dev:amd64 7:4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1

Comment: The link libraries are order dependent.  How come `-lavutil` is at the end of the list?  It'll never have its dependencies fulfilled.

Comment: Regardless of the linking order, the sample code you provided doesn't exhibit the name mangling issue. Your issue with the name mangling is coming through from some other place. you should be able to track the mangled routine to the .o file (and thus the .cpp file) that it originated within from the more full output of the nm command.

Comment: My guess would be you're including ffmpeg headers somewhere else without the `extern "C"` guards

Comment: Ok, the real project is big but there is only one place in the project where I use ffmpeg. So I've removed almost all the dependencies and tested the specified *.o file with the `mn` utility and I get the same result: `_Z16av_log_set_leveli` so that's the file that causes to error, the same file with the `extern "C"` guards.

Comment: ok, I've solved the issue. in one of #include inside #include inside #include ... was `#include avutil.h` not enclosed in the extern "C" guard. sorry for the inattention and thanks for the help